# Heap Corruption when trying to free two dimensional array

Tags: c, heap-memory, heap-corruption

Why does the heap get corrupted when executing this code? I didn't work with memory allocation that much, yet.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char **field, x, _fieldsX, _fieldsY;

    _fieldsX = 8;
    _fieldsY = 16;

    // Allocation
    field = malloc(sizeof(char*) * _fieldsX);
    for (x = 0; x < _fieldsY; x++)
        field[x] = malloc(sizeof(char) * _fieldsY);

    // Freeing
    for (x = 0; x < _fieldsY; x++)
        free(field[x]);
    free(field);
}
```

Comment: Incredible, how fast I got so many answers! Great community!

Is it possible to delete questions? This one was so obvious - I don't think it's of a lot use to someone.

Comment: 1) int main(void) 2) don't use variable names with leading underscores, they are reserved. 3) sizeof(char) == 1, by definition. 4) avoid using char as index; the compiler should warn about this.

Comment: 1) I know that I have to do this for a proper console app. This code will be part of an app for a MC.
2) Thanks. Didn't know that.
3) Right. I'm just always using sizeof. Is this a performance disadvantage?
4) Why shouldn't I do this to save memory?

Comment: 1) Ok. 3) consider using `field = malloc(fieldsx * sizeof *field);` instead. It is less error-prone and will save you some typing. Performance is not relevant (sizeof is a compile-time operator) 4) Assuming a smart compiler the loop index will probably live in a register anyway, so it won't cost you any space. (also consider using unsigned types for indexes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get out of the bounds of the allocated area in the first loop:

```
field = malloc(sizeof(char*) * _fieldsX);

for (x = 0; x < _fieldsY; x++)
    field[x] = malloc(sizeof(char) * _fieldsY);
```

Notice that you are allocating `_fieldsX` items, but the loop goes `_fieldsY` times over that area.

Comment: Man.. don't know how I could not see this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code allocates fields to be _fieldsX in length, but sets _fieldsY elements. This is not correct.